# Bash quote characteristics

Tags: bash

So I am curl'ing some data in the form of a dictionary/json and want to make use of a bash variable. If I create a for loop and enclose the dictionary like:

```
for i in {1..5}; do curl blah blah -d '{"key": "value $i"}'; done
```

Then it will print out "value $i" instead of "value 1". I assume this is because the enclosing single brackets (which prevent bash from expanding variables) are present (even though the actual value line is in double quotes).

Also, if I invert all the quotes (enclose with double, use single in between), bash then puts me on the next line with ">" as if it is expecting more input. Trying to escape characters didn't give me any luck, either.

Comment: it's in single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the colon after `{1..5}` to semi-colon. And  put `$i` inside double quotes.

```
for i in {1..5}; do curl blah blah -d '{"key": "value '$i'"}'; done
```

OR

```
for i in {1..5}; do curl blah blah -d '{"key": "value '"$i"'"}'; done
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake when i typed it into SO. The problem occurs with a semi colon.

Comment: or `for i in {1..5}; do curl blah blah -d '{"key": "value '"$i"'"}'; done`

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue was, because your original answer works fine at least back to bash 3.2 as well as on 4.3 -- as does the version in the comment?

Comment: The original version doesn't have syntactic double-quotes around `$i`. It consists of a single-quoted string (`'{"key": "value '`), then `$i`, then another single-quoted string (`'"}'`). Note that the double-quotes inside the single-quoted strings will be printed, not treated as shell syntax. The second version adds double-quotes around `$i`, which doesn't really matter in this case but is good scripting practice. The times it would matter is when `$i` contained spaces (or other whitespace) and/or shell wildcards.

Answer (score 2):

shell doesn't expand variable inside single quote, use:

```
for i in {1..5}
do
    curl blah blah -d "{\"key\": \"value $i\"}"
done
```